# How dangerous is it to share my iTunes ID?

Tags: itunes

Someone I one shared my iTunes library with, which contained purchased content from the iTunes store, contacted me and asked me for my iTunes ID because music they had copied from library in to their own library was causing iTunes to prompt them for this information.

It seems like I use my iTunes ID for so many things, I don't want someone else to have it.

What's the danger in sharing this information?

Answer (score 9):

The danger is considerably high.

Sharing your iTunes ID with another person enables them to make media purchases from any of Apple's stores using the credit card information associated with the account. This includes, *but is not limited to*:

- iTunes Music Store
- iTunes Movie and TV Store
- iOS App Store
- OS X App Store
- Apple's online store http://store.apple.com/

The would also be able to access your iTunes ID details and change billing information, address information, view purchase history, sign you up for any Apple-based subscription services like iCloud Storage or iTunes Match, etc.

It also allows the user access to your [iCloud account](https://www.icloud.com/) and any email, documents, music, applications, purchases or address book entries you have stored there.

iCloud access could also be used, via [Find my Mac/iPhone/iPad](http://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my-iphone.html), to track your whereabouts if you've enabled the [Find My services](http://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my-iphone.html) on any of your devices. They can also lock or permanently wipe the data from these devices, remotely, using the Find My services.

My advice to you is to tell your acquaintance to buy the tracks with their own money since they are, legally speaking, bound to you and your iTunes account by the terms under which you purchased them.

Comment: +!. In summary: it's a horrible idea

Comment: I agree with Ian completely. Now, sharing is a long term risk, however you could change your password to something you don't mind sharing, have them log in "one last time" and afterwards change the password. Their current copy of your music, apps and movies, etc... will work likely for months before asking again for the password. Just be sure you audit your list of trusted devices and security email for your AppleID. You might even consider enabling [two-step verification for your AppleID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5570) first and then changing the password later.